# Code First Conventions

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first

When using Entity Framework Code First in the mappings using the fluent api I can use Ignore to not map certain classes.

I have a convention where I start some of my classes with the characters `Stub` and `Missing`.

Is there a way in Entity Framework 5 Code First to set a convention that will not map ANY classes beginning with `Stub*` or `Missing*`?

I tried a search but was not able to find anything to help me with this.